# How to get Apache, Ubuntu, and PHP7 to work with HTTP/2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, http2

I have followed the steps mentioned at https://http2.pro/doc/Apache but my website still only serves files as HTTP/1.1. I can see that the mod_http2 is in the config with no errors on restarting Apache:

```
LoadModule http2_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_http2.so
```

And that the site has a fresh SSL cert from LetsEncrypt and the Protocol line in the site config `Protocols h2 http/1.1`, but Chrome still only shows that the files are served as HTTP/1.1.

Is there a step that is missing? Thank you.

Versions:
Apache 2.4.27,
Ubuntu 16.04.3,
PHP 7.0.22

Comment: Just to make sure, you've enabled the module as well with `a2enmod http2`? And `apachectl configtest` doesn't report any errors?

Comment: Yeah, it is in mods-enabled, and apachectl configtest says the syntax is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see the Apache error log, and the message `The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2` was posting there. I followed the troubleshooting steps on the link I used above (https://http2.pro/doc/Apache) and switching to MPM Event and php-fpm fixed the issue.